# SQL Query a table and use LPAD for one column with dtype (smallint) to return values with leading 0's

Tags: sql, teradata-sql-assistant, lpad

There's about 25 columns and I want to query them all while formatting this one column to include leading zeros.

i.e
julianday = 5
I want the data to show 005
julianday = 145
I want the data to show 145

```
SELECT LPAD(julianday, 3 ,'000') FROM date_db
```

My query comes back with an error:
No matching function with signature lpad(smallint, tinyint, string)

1)What am I missing?
2)Can I use *, to query the entire table while formatting that one column?

Comment: Using * will give you all the columns "as is". You have the option of adding the "formatted" version before or after everything else, but if you want to exclude the "unformatted" column then you have to explicitly list all the remaining column names.

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter in lpad needs to be a string so you would have to cast the date to a string, in the required format, before you can use it in lpad

Comment: Since you have to typecast anyway, why not just use explicit formatting instead of LPAD? `CAST(CAST(julianday as format'999') as CHAR(3))` or `TRIM(TO_CHAR(julianday,'000'))` (TO_CHAR adds a leading space for positive values.)